# Twitter Bootstrap 3 into an existing Rails 4 project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to use bootstrap 3 in my rails 4 project but it's not working. I've created a new project just to test the implementation of bootstrap. I read maaaany articles 'til I finally got install. I followed four steps:

1- Add the following gems:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'
```

2- Add the following line into app/stylesheets/application.css

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

3- (Very important!!)

```
Rename de app/stylesheets/application.css file
```

to

```
 app/stylesheets/application.css**.scss**
```

4- add the following line into app/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap
```

When I do this in my new project, its perfect, I can use whatever I want with bootstrap and sass, but following the same steps in my existing rails project I cant.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: you need to describe what goes wrong when you do it in an existing project.

Comment: I just downloaded the files from bootstrap and plugged them in into my rails apps, no need to use gems IMHO. You will need all the css and js files for it to work properly, also you'll need the tags to link the files from their existing folders to your views.

Comment: I dont get any errors, It just doesn't work. But how can it work on the new project?

Comment: @madam all you got to do is download bootstrap, unzip the file and move the css and js files into your rails app, then you can use bootstrap as you would within a regular html file.

Comment: and in what repository do I find these files? Because in the repository I saw many people recommend, it was discontinued and it's linking to another repository, and the new one you must install the gems, because it doesn't have the files .css and .js

Comment: The gems are the better way to handle it. Are you getting any errors in either the browser console or the terminal window when you load a page?